# « Faire pessimiste » ou « rendre pessimiste » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

Je voudrais bien savoir quelle phrase est juste ?

> Ce climat triste le fait pessimiste.
>
> Ce climat triste le rend pessimiste.

Quelle est la différence de signification ?

Comment: Je ne dirais tout simplement pas la première car c'est de l'anglais mal traduit, du moins en Français de France.

Comment: J'ajoute que `fait` est comme `get` en anglais,  si on peux l'éviter au profit d'un autre verbe plus précis, c'est mieux.

Answer (score 5):

Pour comprendre la distinction d'emploi entre « faire » et « rendre » - distinction qui n'existe pas en anglais où on emploie *make* dans le cas présenté dans la question, il suffit des se rappeler que « faire » implique une **action** (et donc est suivi d'un **verbe**) et « rendre » implique un **changement** dans la qualité de quelque chose (et donc est suivi d'un **adjectif**)

Ainsi :

> 1- Ce climat maussade le rend pessimiste.*

Mais :

> 2- Ce climat maussade l'incite à dormir.

Dans la phrase 1 le sujet subit une transformation sous une influence extérieure, il n'agit pas.

Dans la phrase 2 le sujet est poussé à l'action par une influence extérieure.

Autre exemple :

> Mettre toujours la musique à fond rend sourd.
>
> Mettre toujours la musique à fond fait devenir sourd.

J'ai eu besoin d'introduire un verbe (*devenir*) de façon à introduire l’adjectif *sourd* pour exprimer la même idée.

Il ne faut pas confondre avec les cas où « faire » est suivi d'un nom, comme dans les expressions : *faire mal*, *faire peur*, etc., cas où de toutes façons l'anglais a en général un verbe ad-hoc et n'utilise pas *make*.

<sup>* Pour parler du temps on emploiera *maussade* de préférence à *triste*.</sup>